# Prove the Vector Space is Indecomposable into a Direct Sum of Invariant Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $T$ be a Linear Operator on a Finite Dimensional Complex Vector Space $V$

Prove that $V$ with only one Line invariant under $T$ is indecomposable into a Direct Sum of nonzero subspaces invariant under $T$

How do I contradict this by assuming that such a direct sum does exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $V = U \oplus W$(as $T$-module) and $U$ contain our invariant line. But $T_{W}$ has eigenvector $\implies$ there are two invarian lines.